# NeXt UI in OpenDayLight Be

Tags: mininet, sdn, openflow, opendaylight

How to install and use NeXt(Network centric topology)UI feature of ODL Be? 
I have only  theoretical knowledge of NextUI, so someone can explain in detail how to view the topology using NextUI.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The NeXT UI interface is a separate web app that you would run in addition to ODL.
It can be installed using npm or bower on the host machine.

You need to use the restconf interface of ODL to GET the topology data, convert the topology data to a NeXT topology format, and then render the view you define for the data in browser.

The default REST call should look something like this:
localhost:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/flow:1/

check out the Tutorials on:
https://github.com/NeXt-UI/next-tutorials/